# how to add opportunities on VF Page if opportunity owner is same as lead owner?

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce

I want to display opportunities on inline VF page on Lead page layout.
But it is giving error

**List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject**

Here is my code :

Class :

```
public class sampleDetailPageCon {
    public List<Opportunity> oppz;
    //public Opportunity op;
    public Lead lead; 
    public sampleDetailPageCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.lead= (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<Opportunity> getOppz()
    {
        Lead l = [Select id,Name,OwnerId FROM Lead];
        oppz = [Select id, Name, Account.Name, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where OwnerId IN: l.OwnerId limit 10];
        return oppz;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lead SOQL returning all the leads instead of single lead so add your lead.id in that SOQL so that it can get single record.

update your following code as shown below

```
    public List<Opportunity> getOppz()
    {
        /**************updated code**************************/
        Lead l = [Select id,Name,OwnerId FROM Lead where id =: this.lead.id];
        /****************************************/
        if (l.OwnerId== null)
         return null;
        oppz = [Select id, Name, Account.Name, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where OwnerId IN: l.OwnerId limit 10];
        return oppz;
    }
```